# Turn .json "titles" into Array IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to put every title from the reddit frot page into an array using the http://reddit.com/.json file. I have used the same code on another site to return something that only appears a single time. Because "title" appears multiple times I need to put each into an array.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData                      
                                 options:kNilOptions
                                   error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *latestTitles = [json objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSLog(@"titles: %@", latestLoans); 
}
```

I think this should work but I compile titles: (null)

Comment: And what does `error` show??

Comment: BTW, you should go to json.org and study the JSON syntax there.  It will take maybe 10 minutes to learn, and you will spend much less time fumbling in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking at the root object, and expecting an array of titles, which isn't the case.

Your code would work for this JSON structure:

```
{
  "titles":[
    "Some Title",
    "Another Title",
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, that's not what http://reddit.com/.json provides.  It looks more like this:

```
{
  data: {
    children: [
      {
        data: {
          // other data...
          title: "Some Title"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          // other data...
          title: "Another Title"
        }
      }
      // other objects...
    ]
  }
}
```

You'll notice there is no array of titles.  Instead, there is an array of objects, each of which has a `title` property.

You can then traverse the structure, and build an array of titles.

```
NSArray *objects = [[json objectForKey:@"data"]
                            objectForKey:@"children"];

NSMutableArray *titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *object in objects) {
  NSString *title = [[object objectForKey:@"data"]
                               objectForKey:@"title"];
  [titles addObject:title];
}

NSLog(@"titles: %@", titles);
```

---

You must transverse JSON structures.  There is no XPATH for XML equivalent in JSON. You must drill into objects from the root until you get the data you need.  Its simple like that which, believe it or not, is really awesome.

Comment: Thank you ver much, I'm used to XPath and I assumed they worked they same. I have read more on it and understand it significantly more but I really appreciate the help.